# unable to read my array values in my TableRow

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in Flutter , i created a List of Club and i wanted to add them to my table but it seems that when i try to edit the content of Text() by clubs[index].field can not work , i do not know why since this method of access works with listview but did not work with my example here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LeagueBoard extends StatelessWidget {

  List<Club> clubs = [ Club("Manchester City","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/thumb/b/ba/Logo_Manchester_City_2016.svg/1200px-Logo_Manchester_City_2016.svg.png","1","77","17","15","1","1",25,5),
    Club("Chelsea","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/thumb/5/51/Logo_Chelsea.svg/768px-Logo_Chelsea.svg.png","2","70","17","13","2","3",19,8),];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text("TableBoard"),
     backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
     elevation: 0.0,
   ),
   body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         TopRow(),
         ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
          // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           itemCount: 14,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) {
             return TableRow(index: index);
           },
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
    );
  }
}

class TopRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopRow({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    TextStyle textStyle2 = TextStyle(fontSize: 13);

    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
            child: Text('#'),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Container(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Team')),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('MP', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('W', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('D', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('L', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('GD', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('Pts', style: textStyle),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 5,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey[800],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}

class TableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  const TableRow({
    this.index,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////linkwell
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    TextStyle textStyle2 = TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black38, width: 0.2),
        color: index == 0  ? Colors.yellow[100] : Colors.purpleAccent[20],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(//iinkwell
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 30,
            height: 40,
            color: index < 2
                ? Colors.blue
                : index == 2

                ? Colors.red[400]
                : index > 11
                ? Colors.red[800]
                : Colors.grey[700],
            child: Text(
              (index + 1).toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20),
          Row(children: [
            FlutterLogo(
              size: 24.0,
            ),
            Text(this.clubs[index].toString(), style: textStyle2),
          ],),

          Spacer(),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 28,
            child: Text('${index + 1}', style: textStyle2),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Container(
            width: 5,
            height: 20,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey[600],
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 2, 5),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Club {

  String name;
  String image;
  String rank;
  String points;
  String matches;
  String wins;
  String loss;
  String draws;
  int goals;
  int goalsIn;

  Club(this.name,this.image,this.rank,this.points, this.matches,this.wins,this.loss,this.draws,this.goals,this.goalsIn);

}
```

Here what i have tried , what i am trying to do is to make this table rows values come from my List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem that club does not exist in the context of TableRow, you are passing the index into TableRow, but it does not pass the club itself, club is declared in Leagueboard, but it does not mean that it exists in the context of your child TableRow.

LeagueBoard Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("TableBoard"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TopRow(),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 14,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TableRow(index: index, clubs: clubs);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

TableRow

```
class TableRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;
  final List<Club> clubs;
  const TableRow({
    this.index,
    this.clubs,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////linkwell
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
}
```